# Encontrar el mayor número de un vector/array en C

Tags: c

Esto es lo que tengo del vector, no se como encontrar el número mayor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    int vector[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("vector[%i]\n\n\f ",i);
            scanf("%i",vector);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Encontrar el mayor número de un vector/array en C

Primero que nada, tu programa tiene una falla en esta línea:

```
scanf("%i",vector);
```

Lo que estás enviando, es la dirección base del arreglo, es decir, en ningún momento estarás llenando el vector (a excepción del primero elemento).

La forma correcta sería de esta forma:

```
scanf("%i",&vector[i]);
```

De ese modo, en cada iteración, envías la dirección de memoria de cada elemento del vector y por ende, el vector se llenará correctamente.

Con respecto a como encontrar el valor mayor de un vector, el algoritmo sería:

- Declaramos dos variables, la primera (puede ser `int mayor`) para que guarde el valor mayor y la segunda (puede ser `int posMayor`) para que almacene la posición/índice del elemento mayor.
- Luego, asumimos que el primer elemento del vector es el mayor (ese será el valor por defecto de `int mayor`).
- Ejecutamos un bucle donde en cada iteración verificamos si algún elemento del vector llega a ser mayor a la variable `int mayor`, si se cumple la condición, actualizamos la variable donde guardamos el valor mayor y también la posición.

El código quedaría de esta forma:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int mayor;
    int posMayor = 0;

    int n;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    int vector[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("vector[%i]\n\n\f ",i);
            scanf("%i",&vector[i]);
    }

    mayor = vector[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(vector[i] > mayor)
        {
            mayor = vector[i];
            posMayor = i;
        }
    }

    printf("El numero mayor fue: %d (indice: %d)\n", mayor, posMayor);
    return 0;
}
```

También debo recalcar que los [VLA](https://www.reidatcheson.com/c/programming/2015/12/07/vlas.html) (Variable Length Arrays) no son recomendable, debido que, no se puede detectar si la asignación de memoria sucedió con éxito o no. Por esa razón, se recomienda usar memoria dinámica.

Usando la función [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) podemos crear un arreglo de X elementos de forma segura:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int mayor;
    int posMayor = 0;
    int* vector;
    //Pedimos el tamaño del vector
    int n;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    //Reservamos memoria para crear el arreglo dinámico 
    vector = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(vector == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Hubo una fallo al momento de asignar memoria!");
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("vector[%i]\n\n\f ",i);
            scanf("%i",&vector[i]);
    }

    mayor = vector[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(vector[i] > mayor)
        {
            mayor = vector[i];
            posMayor = i;
        }
    }

    printf("El numero mayor fue: %d (indice: %d)\n", mayor, posMayor);

    //Liberamos la memoria.
    free(vector);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> No se como encontrar el número mayor.

El algoritmo que se suele usar para estos casos, es: mediante una variable que *arrastre* el primer valor, comparar dicho valor con todos los elementos y reemplazando el valor de la variable de *arrastre* con el comparado cuando éste sea mayor:

```
int mayor = vector[0];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    mayor = mayor < vector[i] ? vector[i] : mayor;
}
```

Pero ¿por qué recorrer el vector dos veces (una para rellenar y otra para buscar el número mayor)? Recórrelo una única vez, busca el valor mayor a medida que guardas datos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    int *vector = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    int mayor = INT_MIN;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("vector[%d]\n\n\f ", i);
        scanf("%i", &vector[i]);
        mayor = mayor < vector[i] ? vector[i] : mayor;
    }

    printf("El mayor numero de la lista es %d", mayor);
    free(vector);

    return 0;
}
```

Si te fijas, usamos la macro [`INT_MIN`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) como valor inicial para `mayor`, para garantizar que el primer valor de dicha variable será el menor valor que pueda almacenar un entero (`int`), de lo contrario el algoritmo podría dar falsos positivos.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBBT4NAEIXPzK@YYGigrYYWlSqoJw892JM3bcwKi06y7JqFNlHT346z0Jp29rDLe2/4Zrc4L5TQH113RrpQm1Ji3rQlmYvPeziRFL2faopqahunAekWa0E63BoqI/gFzyk6A68phK5CPyB/OtJRNhjjrSxaY/EOw/4zqoVSpgg1jrGhH2kqp0ccH/K1@O7Ty9Xz29Ny5eTK2L6XWI4z3nLG4WRCETLd@7JsMncAvQTl@lXzqtCfIrkxjgfD0T5G69464IY9x38XH47Ot4PPDTue5wB8VPs2vamlNcgPpQQqalqBssGgZFwfcKTKShkOf@zvamW7sZrvA7uum8Uwg/kckiSBSy64cgXXXJCmKSwWcAMx/AE)</kbd>.